# Changing height of container view with height Constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, container-view

I have one view **firstViewController** wich has one ***container view***. The container view has the following constraints:

[image: ContainerView Constraints]

The height is 0 because programatically I will change heightConstraint to new value.

This is what I have in my **containerView:**

[image: ContainerView Controller]

The problem is when I pin one of the objects in containerView to the bottom of the super view they are visible on the firstViewController even when the height of the containerView is 0, so they shouldn't be visible.....

If I don't pin any object to the bottom of containerView they aren't visible in the firstViewController

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question but you could hide the objects from view until you need them. For example with the buttons you could do:

```
button.hidden = true
```

Then when you need to show the buttons just call the hidden attribute to false.